# redirect to another page after ajax function

Tags: ajax, redirect, download, counter

Can anyone help me with, I am trying to create a download counter to my website.
I have a ajax script that counts up by 1 when the users clicks the download link, the issue I am having is on some browsers it goes to the download link before completing the ajax count script.
Is there a way that I can redirect to the download file once the script has completed. At the moment I have as follows

**This is the link :-**

```
<a href='downloads/".$downfile."' onclick=\"Counter('$referid');\"'>Download File</a>
```

**This is the counter script:-**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Counter(id)
        {
      $.get("clickcounter.php?id="+id);
      {
          return false;
      }
    }
</script>
```

This is the php script (clickcounter.php)

```
<?php
include('dbutils.php'); 

$referid = $_GET['id'];

$q = "SELECT * FROM downloads WHERE downid =".$referid;
$r = mysql_query($q);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r))
{
$click = stripslashes(trim($row['downcount']));
$download = $row['downfile'];


}

$countup = $click + 1;

$qUpdate = "UPDATE downloads
SET downcount=$countup
WHERE downid=$referid";
$rUpdate = mysql_query($qUpdate);

?>
```

Comment: The php above can be simplified quite a bit by changing `SET downcount=$countup` to `SET downcount=downcount + 1`. That way you avoid the SELECT completely.

Answer (score 0):

A few relatively small modifications should solve the problem. First, change the onclick to the following:

```
onclick=\"Counter('$referid', this); return false;\"
```

What we have done is to send in **this** as the second argument to the Counter function so we have a reference to the clicked link. Secondly, we have added **return false**, which blocks the browser from navigating to the url specified in the href.

The modified counter function looks like this:

```
function Counter(id, link) {
   $.get("clickcounter.php?id=" + id, function() {
      location.href = $(link).attr("href");
   });
}
```

We now have a reference to the clicked link. A function has now been specified as the second argument to $.get(). This is the success-function, which is called when the ajax call has been successfully called. Inside that function we now redirect to the url specified in the href attribute on the clicked link.

I feel I should point out that the recommended way is to bind the onclick using jQuery separate from the html. The referid can be stored in a data attribute (which I chose to call data-rid):

```
<a href='downloads/".$downfile."' class='dl' data-rid='$referid'>Download File</a>
```

Then you bind the onclick for all download links (a elements with a "dl" class):

```
$(function() {
    $("a.dl").click(function() {
       var id = $(this).attr("data-rid");
       var href = $(this).attr("href");

       $.get("clickcounter.php?id=" + id, function() {
          location.href = href;
       });   

       return false;
    });
});​
```

(I feel I should point out that the code has not been tested, so it's possible that a typo has snuck in somewhere)